# Scaffold-DbContext: command not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

i try to reverse engnieer my models from an existing database, but the command: `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(db);Database=xxxx;Trusted_connection=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`
doesn´t work.

I get the error message like in the title.

I installed the Nuget packeges :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

and i don´t know why it doesn´t work.(`dotnet ef` commands works)
I´m sure its a little problem but i can´t find the solution. Please help me

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4">
      <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation">
      <Version>1.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 10):

#### This worked for me

use **`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`** instead of `Scaffold-DbContext`

for instance

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -c ContextName -o OutPutFolder
```

run  `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold -h` to see options u can pass !

Comment: I needed to use "dotnet-ef"

Answer (score 8):

Install Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore tools nuget package in your project by running the following command in Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 1.1.2
```

This will install the Cmdlets to run Database first approach via Package Manager Console. For details visit https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/

Answer (score 4):

Modify the `.csproj` file to include the following section:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference
        Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"
        Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This step is only necessary if the `.csproj` file wasn't automatically modified to add the entry when the Tools package was installed. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7358.

Restore the packages:

```
dotnet restore
```

Now, check your dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command.